# Shell Script Invocation Error

Tags: objective-c, ios, openssl, xcode4.2, sqlcipher

I am using open ssl in my project. I was running this project successfully in xcode 4.0.2. Recently I updated to XCode 4.2. But its showing build errors. here is the error log

> Make[1]:
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2: No
>   such file or directory

Could someone help please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zach,

Are you using [the openssl-xcode project](https://github.com/sqlcipher/openssl-xcode) that we (Zetetic) published for use with [SQLCipher](https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher)? If so, you should be able to solve this problem by updating to the latest versions of openssl-xcode and sqlcipher from Github. If you used git to clone them, this should update them without a problem:

```
$ cd your_project/openssl-xcode
$ git pull origin master
$ cd your_project/sqlcipher
$ git pull origin master
```

The build scripts were updated for use with Xcode 4.2 and LLVM, should work without a hitch. We've updated [the tutorial](http://sqlcipher.net/ios-tutorial/) for Xcode 4.2 as well.